# How to do a sum of a function over all divisors of an integer with Maple?

Tags: number-theory, summation, maple, divisor-sum, multiplicative-function

I'd like to define `sumdiv` in Maple such that this:

```
with(numtheory);
f:=x->x^2;
sumdiv(f(d)*mobius(100/d), d=1..100);
```

would do a sum on all divisors `d` of $100$.

**How to do such a sum over divisors in Maple?**

Here's what I've tried:

```
isdivisible:=(a,b)->if a mod b = 0 then 1 else 0 fi;
sum(f(d)*mobius(100/d)*isdivisible(100,d), d=1..100);
```

but even if `isdivisible(100,d)` is $0$ (i.e. $d$ not divisible by $100$), it tries to evaluate `mobius(100/d)` anyway which is impossible, thus an error.

> Error, (in mobius) invalid arguments

Comment: I prefer Matlab...

Comment: @hyprfrcb How would the code look like in Matlab?

Answer (score 3):

Just use `divisors` function:

```
> divisors(100);
{1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 20, 25, 50, 100}
```

So for example:

```
> add(f(d)*mobius(100/d), d in divisors(100));
7200
```

The `add` allows to iterate over set as oposed to `sum` which supports only range `a..b`.

Comment: Important to note, I think, is that you can be sure that in-built functions like `divisors` are highly optimised.

Comment: Thanks @Sil. I use good old Maple 7, it seems that `d in ...` is not allowed in `add`. Which minimum version is needed for this?

Comment: @Basj Hm I am not sure, I am using Maple 2017. But anyway you can get around this by simply indexing the set, something like `divs:=divisors(100): add(f(divs[i])*mobius(100/divs[i]), i=1..nops(divs));`

Answer (score 2):

In Matlab, `D` is a vector containing all the divisors, for any `n`:

```
n=10;
k=1:n;
D=K(rem(n,k)==0);
s=sum(D)
```

Edit: The sum of a function `f` over the divisors of `n`. Note the `.` operator before the `^` and `*` operators, for applying them component-wise instead of matrix-wise (default).

```
n=10;
k=1:n;
D=K(rem(n,k)==0);
f=@(x)(x.^2+2.*x+sin(x)+1);
s=sum(f(D))
```

Comment: Thanks @hyprfrcb, but I don't want to do the `sum of all divisors of n` but the sum of a function, when the variable goes through all divisors of n.

Comment: "**How to do such a sum over divisors in Maple?**". Since this answer is in the language of Matlab, how does this answer the question?

Comment: @Therkel I asked the OP and he wanted to see the solution under Matlab

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by adding up the results from the Maple command `numtheory[divisors]`, or you could go more directly to the Maple command `numtheory[sigma]`.

```
restart;

`+`(op(numtheory[divisors](100)));

                                 217

numtheory[sigma](100);

                                 217

F1 := n -> `+`(op(numtheory[divisors](n))):
F2 := n -> numtheory[sigma](n):

seq( F1(i), i = 10 .. 20 );

             18, 12, 28, 14, 24, 24, 31, 18, 39, 20, 42

seq( F2(i), i = 10 .. 20 );

             18, 12, 28, 14, 24, 24, 31, 18, 39, 20, 42
```

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding: you speak about `the sum of all divisors of n`, thus the use of `sigma`. I speak about the `sum of f(d), where d goes through the set of all divisors of n` (for a function `f`).

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood. In that case you can just take Sil's suggestion, which in older Maple versions could be done with `add(f(d)*mobius(100/d), d=divisors(100))`